# How to convince Kafka brokers to assign workers to my topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We're got a (Confluent) managed kafka installation with 5 brokers and 2 connector hosts. I have two topics which never get any consumers assigned to them, despite repeated starting and stopping of the connectors which are supposed to listen for them. This configuration was running until recently (and no, nothing has changed - we've done an audit to confirm).

What, if anything, can I do to force assignment of consumers to these topics?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred for two reasons: (1) I had mistakenly installed new versions of the PostgreSQL and SQLServer JDBC connectors {which conflicted with the already-installed versions}, and (2) not understanding that *source* connectors do *not* have Consumer Groups assigned to them.

Getting past the "well duh, of course sources don't have consumers", another vital piece of information (thankyou to the support team at Confluent for this) is that you can see where your connector is up to by reading the private or hidden topic `connect-offsets`. Once you have that, you can then check your actual DB query and see what it is returning then (if necessary) reset your connector's offset.